# Derivative of matrices and vectors

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Consider:

```
e(t) = A(x)*u(t)
```

Where A is a matrix which depend on x and u is a vector depending on t. If I were to do the derivatives:

```
d/dt e(t)
d/dx e(t)
```

Can I differentiate the matrix first and then multiply it with u(t) (For the upper eq)? And similar with the lower? That is does a derivative operator commute with these linear algebra objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since for $A(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $u(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$,

$A(x)u(t)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{j=1}^n a_{1j}(x)u_j(t)\\
\sum_{j=1}^n a_{2j}(x)u_j(t)\\
\vdots\\
\sum_{j=1}^n a_{mj}(x)u_j(t)\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

and the derivatives of $e(t,x)$ are done componentwise.